# MySQL Compute int size if knowing the max ID

Tags: mysql

I want to convert a CSV database into a MySQL one, I know I will never add any new row in the database tables. I know the max ID of each table, for example : 9898548.

What should be the proper way to compute the int size ? Does a CEIL(LOG2(last_id)) could be sufficient for this ? With my example, it would be LOG2(9898548) = 23.2387 so int(24) ? is this correct ?

Comment: the int size is alway 4 bytes... int(24) is also 4 bytes the 24 only counts for zerofull option.. you don't have to computer this the MySQL documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) is very clear about the max values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're defining your table and you know your max values you can refer to the max table sizes. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html for a table of numeric sizes.

IDs are usually positive so you can use the unsigned numbers.  In your case 9898548 is less than 16777215 (the unsigned MEDIUMINT max value) so that would be the most space efficient storage option.  So your calculation is correct.  You need 24 bits or 3 bytes, or a UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT.

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (id UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT PRIMARY KEY);
```

The brackets with numbers inside are to help MySQL display the number correctly, they don't do anything to the storage size.  So INT(11) and INT (24), can both sure the same range of numbers.  But the one defined INT (11) will only display a number with a column width of equivalent to 11 digits even if the number is smaller.  See 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

"This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case, you need an integer type with a least 24 bits (equals 3 bytes). The smallest in MySQL satisfying this is UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT, according to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

Edit: Added the UNSIGNED.